# Login issues in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I have code result like this:

[image]

I want to login to an account, but I don't know how to modify the "welcome" message so that that message only come when we log in to an account. Does anyone know how to modify that? I'm using Yii2 framework.
Here is my code:
PATH: `frontend\views\layout\main.php:`

https://pastebin.com/Qqj1fb8f

and the index PATH: frontend\views\site\index:

https://pastebin.com/UwCezAmn

Please help me to solve that problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: post the related  code (only) and not a link to ypu pastebin ..  and try to explain better your need

Answer (score 1):

tipicallly  in you layout (eg: views\layout\main.php) you some code like this  login

```
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/user/login']];
    }
```

asn you can use this menu item call for a  controller/action  (in this case /user/login)

then in the corresponding  controller/action
you should  have some  code like this

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = \Yii::createObject(LoginForm::className());

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }

    return $this->render('login', [
        'model'  => $model,
        'module' => $this->module,
    ]);
}
```

as you can see if the user is logged  (not isGuest)

```
  if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $this->goHome();
    }
```

in this case is invoked  the goHome  function

but you could invoke an your render for the view and you prefer with the welcome message you prefer 
eg:

```
       return $this->render('my_welcome', [
        'model'  => $model,
     ]);
```